# Can I add USB outlets to bath/hall lighting circuit box (not GFCI)?

Tags: bathroom, gfci, nec

My bathroom, inside near door, has a 2-gang box, containing 2 light switches, powering combination ceiling light and fan. This box is fed by hallway lighting circuit, and the work box is not covered by GFCI.

The changes I want to make are:

- Exchange both switches with a "2 horizontal switch" device, freeing up a gang (example: Leviton 5634-W)
- Install a USB-ONLY outlet (example: Leviton USB4P)

My question is whether this change is "to code" (NEC)? I am in Northeast USA (NH).

For completeness: My bathroom electrical outlets ARE on a different circuit, in a different work box, and yes that is protected by GFCI.

The question is about adding a USB "outlet" to an area that normally requires all outlets to be GFI. My understanding is what I plan would be OK because these are low-voltage.

Comment: Fascinating question! Typically low voltage has different rules, including USB. But on the other hand, the high voltage is "right there". If it wasn't in a bathroom (or kitchen or other GFCI required area) then there would not be any question. So just a comment because hopefully one of the pros has a real answer. In a quick search, I couldn't find any combo. GFCI + USB - probably because the combination is just so unusual - more & more people have the GFCI upstream (breaker or another part of the circuit) that the combo. would be a rare need.

Comment: Update: Legrand now sells one. 

https://www.legrand.us/gfci/gfci-usb-outlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No, Class 2 power outlets (such as USB receptacles) are *not* required to have GFCI protection

This can be drawn from the fact that the GFCI requirements in NEC 210.8(A) are specifically restricted to 125V, 15 and 20A receptacles:

> **(A) Dwelling Units.** All 125-volt, single-phase, 15- and 20-ampere receptacles installed in the locations specified in
>   210.8(A)(1) through (10) shall have ground-fault circuit-interrupter protection for personnel.
>
> (1) Bathrooms

and is further justified by the definition of Class 2 circuit in 725.2 already taking shock hazards into account:

> **Class 2 Circuit.** The portion of the wiring system between the
>   load side of a Class 2 power source and the connected equip‐
>   ment. Due to its power limitations, a Class 2 circuit considers
>   safety from a fire initiation standpoint and provides acceptable
>   protection from electric shock.

(See also the fact that 210.8 is not referenced in NEC 725.3.)

Comment: Perfect answer; thank you. The interpretation and citations resolve my immediate question, and give me a reference reading point for my curiosity.   In addition since this information isn't well-understood among home inspectors, it helps if/when it's time to sell the house.

Answer (score 0):

Either install a GFCI breaker for the USB outlet, or install it downstream of another GFCI outlet.
[image: Example Wiring]

Comment: Thanks Marcellus. Can you add a comment why you feel this is required by the NEC (if you are saying so.. that was the core of my question).   My understanding is what I am trying to improve, but as I understand -- in a bath, lighting does not go behind GFCI. Or to restate that, only 120V outlets go behind GFCI.   If a 5v USB device fails in any manner possible, that device could never trip the GFCI, so it does not seem like there is a benefit.  I'm not resisting the advice I want to learn what section of the code requires this.

Comment: Per 210.8(A)(6), GFCI protection is required for all 15A and 20A, 125V receptacles that serve kitchen countertop surfaces in a dwelling unit... Therefore it is not required by code for a 5V (3A) USB.  But remember the purpose of GFCI is to protect people from severe electrical shock and most GFCI can since inflow and outflow current differences of just 4mA.